# Insert sql query result inside stored procedure in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have stored procedure in which i store whole query inside string and then execute that. Now i want to store that execute result into temporary table for further processing. 
Something like below :

Exec @Mainsql   -- this returns me query result and i need to insert its result to temp table

I tried something like this:

```
Select * Into #TempTable
   From         
      Exec @MainSQL
```

But It is lacking in syntax i guess.

So, i need result of mainsql into temptable

Comment: I did, i got this error. Do i need to specify all column names one by one. !!! An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable AS 
Exec @MainSQL
```

Comment: I did, i got this error. Do i need to specify all column names one by one. !!! An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. –

Comment: Just a moment, I think it worked, i will get back to u

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody you have to define `#TempTable` this first. `select into` creates the table and insert the data in it but for `insert into`, you need to create the temp table first

Comment: I tried this . Select Into #TempTable  Exec  @MainSQL , but it says  incorrect keyword near into

Comment: If I do something like this . Declare TempTable table and give all columns which will be returned by mainsql. It will be cumbersome. Is there not a better way.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. This is error i got @SaharshShah

Comment: Please help @SaharshShah

Answer (score 0):

You must create Temp Table first, You have to define all columns which will be returned from procedure, if you need to insert data using Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC [ProcedureName]
```

Another option is to use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190312.aspx), if you do not know returned columns :

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC DBName.Schema.ProcedureName')
```